# Как обновить таблицу?

Tags: sql

Есть БД `rk` в ней таблица `dbo.RDRBP`. Есть ещё БД `rk_new` и в ней точно такая же таблица. Как обновить таблицу в `rk_new` из таблицы в `rk`.
Я написал вот это:

`USE rk_new
INSERT INTO dbo.RDRBP SELECT * FROM rk.dbo.RDRBP`

Но вылетает ошибка: Сообщение 8101, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 2
Значение столбца идентификаторов в таблице "dbo.RDRBP" может указываться явно только при использовании списка столбцов и когда IDENTITY_INSERT установлен в ON.
Что делать подскажите.

Comment: Вы хотите именно обновить таблицу rk_new или она у вас пустая и вы хотите перелить все данные из таблицы rk ?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT rk_new.dbo.RDRBP
()
SELECT ..
FROM rk.dbo.RDRBP
```

В список столбцов напишите все важные столбцы, кроме ID. Если нужно перенести с ID, то на время переноса отключит идентити у столбца таблицы в базе rk_new